# Get plot to show up in a dynamically generated tabSet RShiny

Tags: r, tabs, shiny

I have the following (simplified) Shiny app.
I am trying to generate as many tabs as selected rows in the top table with one graph showing on each tab. I cannot get the graph to show getting `Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'` somewhere in that `lapply` or subsequent `do.call`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

The UI consisting of one table and space for the tabs I'm trying to show there :

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test"),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'tableCurrencies'))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput("selectedTabs")
    )
  )
)
```

The `server` including the reactive function to catch the selected rows.

```
server <- function(input,output){
  output$tableCurrencies <-   DT::renderDataTable({datatable(data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=rnorm(10)))})

  origTable_selected <- reactive({
    ids <- input$tableCurrencies_rows_selected
    return(ids)
  })
  output$selectedTabs <- renderUI({
    myTabs <- lapply(origTable_selected(),function(i) {

      a <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(50))})
      return(tabPanel(i,plotOutput(a)))
    })
    return(do.call(tabsetPanel,myTabs))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you use

```
# context server/rederUI
plot = renderPlot({hist(rnorm(50)})
...
plotOutput(plot)
```

Checking the documentation, you will see that this is incorrect usage

> plotOutput(**outputId**, ...)
>
> **outputId**: output variable to read the plot/image from.

You actually passed an objec of class `shiny.render.function` to the output function. However, the only valid values are (id) strings. I'm surprised there is still no error thrown by shiny since a lot of people have that issue.

Here is a working version. You will have to assign a new `output` slot for each of your plots.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Test"),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'tableCurrencies'))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput("selectedTabs")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$tableCurrencies <- DT::renderDataTable({datatable(data.frame(
    a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10)))})
  
  origTable_selected <- reactive({
    ids <- input$tableCurrencies_rows_selected
    return(ids)
  })
  output$selectedTabs <- renderUI({
    print(origTable_selected())
    myTabs <- lapply(origTable_selected(), function(i) {
      outname <- paste0("plot-", i)                        # this
      output[[outname]] <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(50))})   # was
      return(tabPanel(i, plotOutput(outname)))             # wrong
    })
    return(do.call(tabsetPanel,myTabs))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I quite like that ui design by the way

Comment: Shamelessly stolen and modified from another SO answer!

Comment: At least you're humble about it. Make sure to not put spaces into IDs since they will be used as is in your HTML document,